# EXCEL VBA 1004 Runtime Errors Caused by Using OFFSET

Tags: excel, vba

A run-time error occurs in the OFFSET portion of a process that finds cells with the same data in different sheets and flags the corresponding dates for those cells

I've put the offset value of the Search Cell in the String and also put it in the Range type.

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 


Sub compare()

    Dim SearchRange, SearchCell, Dtt2, StdRange, StdCell As Range
    Dim Dtlist As Range
    Dim v1, DtCell, Dtv, Dtt, CurrDtv, FirstAddress, Standard As String
    Dim r As Long
    Dim maxr As Integer
    Dim Dt As Date

    'Dt = Worksheets("EOB").Range("H3").Value
    'Dtv = DateValue(Dt)
    Set Dtlist = Worksheets("2019").UsedRange.Columns("A")
    Set StdRange = Worksheets("EOB").Columns("C")    
    Set SearchRange = Worksheets("2019").Columns("B")    
    maxr = Sheet2.UsedRange.Rows.Count    
    MsgBox "Sheet2에 있는 " & maxr & "개의 Data가 비교되었습니다"

    With Sheet3.UsedRange    
        For r = 1 To maxr    

            Standard = Sheet2.Cells(r, 3).Address   
            Set StdCell = Worksheets("EOB").Range(Standard)   
            v1 = Sheet2.Cells(r, 3).Value  
            Set SearchCell = SearchRange.Find(v1, , xlValues, xlWhole) 
            DtCell = Sheet3.Cells(r, 1).Value


            If Not SearchCell Is Nothing Then    
                FirstAddress = SearchCell.Address   
                Do

                    If SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value <= Date And SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value > DateAdd("m", -6, Now) Then
                        StdCell.Offset(, 1) = 1
                    ElseIf SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value <= DateAdd("m", -6, Now) And SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value > DateAdd("yyyy", -1, Now) Then
                        StdCell.Offset(, 1) = 2
                    Else: StdCell.Offset(, 1) = 3
                    End If

                    Set SearchCell = .FindNext(SearchCell) 
                Loop While Not SearchCell Is Nothing And SearchCell.Address <> FirstAddress 


            ElseIf SearchCell Is Nothing Then    
                StdCell.Interior.Color = RGB(255, 180, 180)
            End If

        Next
        Worksheets("TEST").Range("A2") = Dtv

    End With
End Sub



 If SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value <= Date And SearchCell.Offset(, -1).Value > DateAdd("m", -6, Now) Then  

 ----->  
Say 1004 runtime errors occur here
```

Comment: what mean "since colum offset"?

Comment: If the compare sheet is B, OFFSET -1 will result in column A ㅠㅠ

Comment: Before trying to `Offset`, can you `Debug.Print SearchCell.Address`?

Comment: This line might be causing problems: `SearchCell = .FindNext(SearchCell)`, first search is inside `SearchRange` and next are inside `Sheet3.UsedRange`

Comment: Not the cause of your problem, but `Dim SearchRange, SearchCell, Dtt2, StdRange, StdCell As Range` only declares the last item as `Range`. The others will all be type `Variant`.  In VBA, you must declare the type of each variable separately eg:  `Dim SearchRange as Range, SearchCell as Range, Dtt2 as Range, StdRange as Range, StdCell As Range`